Can my necromancer have this bridge built with those constraints?
Long story short I got a very powerful necromancer living on an island that is 33 kilometers from the nearest land mass. He wants to create a mega bridge to connect his island to the continent.
The bridge length will be around 33 kilometers. It needs to be at least 25 meters above sea level. And the width is 24 meters.
Also there are 10 checkpoints. Each having a tower on both sides, not counted towards the width. And the towers can hold a 100 soldiers. But manned by 20 soldiers at all times. Basically a small castle. It should have basic housing, soldiers are rotated daily. It does not have to have a well and a grand armory. But it has to be comfortable enough and have a stable to accommodate at least half a dozen horses.
Water conditions are bad. Depths range from about 50 to 250 meters. 3°C-  10°C temperature depending on the season. Currents are not too strong between his island and the continent.
But who cares. Your supervisors can direct work from above the water.
It should not take more than 7 years to build. The shorter the more rewards the project head and all the living workers get. But delays are expected.
The necromancer has lots of money and resources. The technology level is early 1700s. No machines yet, no electricity. This allows him to hire the greatest engineers.
They have access to any and everything up to that point. Using granite, erecting natural barriers, coating the stones, making them rounded...etc
His secret weapon is in his workforce. Obviously he has skilled human workers and engineers and masons...etc. But the greatest asset is in the mindless reanimated corpses.

They don't need rest.
They can work underwater
They can work around the clock
They can be tied to poles so the current does not sweep them away.
They can be ordered to perform low level human tasks. Not dissimilar to construction workers.
They can not be expected to do complicated stuff like mix chemicals.
The work force can be expanded to include any animal available on earth. It can be killed and reanimated easily.
The number of undead is not an issue. They are also expendable.

The way they work is that a supervisor holds a scepter that controls a set group of them. Giving clear orders in a particular language, all of them will perform this task. For example if ordered to dig, they will keep digging until ordered to stop. They can be ordered to lay stones on top of each other they will keep doing it until it is no longer possible.
My question is this possible with those conditions? If yes how long would it take?
If no. What needs to change in my world or workers to establish that?
NB
I'm sure I will get someone commenting on this vanity project and how it would be more practical to use ships. That is true. But vanity projects happen in reality. My own country is having such a project right now. So. Please. Lets not act like reality is reasonable.
Also other stuff such as: Why would be people fine with using the undead? Is outside the scope of this question. Similarly the availability of resources. I just have on question, one issue and need it solved. I'd have used reality check tag but it's not replaced with science based, I believe.

Do you care what the bridge is made out of? Are you presuming that most of the supports reach to the bottom, or can we use any architecture in the 1700's, or any architecture we can think of now with 1700's materials?

I think your question fails when you state "infinite money and resources". With that, anything is possible,

Can the bridge be made not just by the undead, but of them? How many undead are available? Also, how many living people? I note you've the science-based tag, did you mean to use the reality-check one?

I say story-based, especially with "number of undead is of no concern". You order them to move a mountain and make a land bridge to the other side, no need of architecture, just a good old dam.

I agree with @L.Dutch with infinite money and ressources you can just drop infinite stones into the ocean until pile forms a bridge. Then build your checkpoints ontop of that.

@RobertRapplean, It should be a bridge. It can't be a bunch of ships put together. It also can't be made of the undead or just pure magic. It should be a bridge.

@L.Dutch while I have to tread carefully talking to a mod. You really think so? Ok. I'll give you infinite money and infinite resources to cure cancer in 7 years, to sent a ship to the Andromeda galaxy, to invent a drug that makes people grow limbs, to build a teleporter that can send people to Mars. All within 7 years and with our current tech.

@Escapeddentalpatient, No. It has to be a bridge. How the heck do you even make a bridge of the undead? They are just  reanimated, they don't have super powers or anything. It will be used to transport goods and people. I thought the reality-check tag was deleted and merged with the science based. I said that in my question. Correct me if I'm wrong though

@datacube,
I get it. Actively ignoring my other constraints in the question that make the full point clear in order to just get pedantic is fun. It's like: If I ignore what he said here then I can make the question look wrong. Let me do that.
Can emperor Augustus with the full resources of the Roman Empire build a space ship?
Probably not. So. Why does it matter that when I make a point about that money and resources not being a problem it matters?
Full context is clear. But reading a question with the intend to help is hard. All good

It hasn't. It's the [tag:internal-consistency] tag now - slightly different from reality-check. As to bridge-of-the-dead, ants manage it - though the strength to size scale is different. But an interlocking pile of bones serves as well as many things.

@Escapeddentalpatient. thank you so much. I fixed it. I love using that tag since...you know how this site works.

I meant this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontoon_bridge

The deepest bridge pylons with modern technology are 74m.  You just can't overcome the force flowing water would impart on a 250m tall pylon without much better than 1700's tech.  I mean, you could build an artificial isthmus, just keep dumping rubble into the sea until it's above sea level all the way across the body of water, but that won't look like a bridge at all.

@Ryan_L Though the deepest off-shore oil platforms are in hundreds of metres of water (~300 m/1000 feet IIRC). I'm no engineer, but I think they would probably experience similar strains on the structure as a bridge would, though without the lateral effect from the bridge itself.

With infinite money and workforce, pile up rocks underwater until the sea bottom rises up to ~ -20m along a ~2km wide underwater platform: this requires 33x2x0.25=16km^3 rock, less than the upper half of Mount Everest. Build your bridge on this platform.

Oh and all along, don't listen to the myriad military engineers who will plead day and night for a causeway in stead of a bridge. Maintenance and security headache and all that.

FYI OP, such a structure already exists on Earth. Look up Rama's Bridge. It's an artificial bridge built between Shri Lanka and the Southernmost tip of India during Medieval times.

Issue #1: water is too deep to make piers using such technology
Because water currents are so much stronger than wind currents, and because they need to support the superstructure of the bridge itself, bridge piers have a maximum depth you can make them before you risk having your bridge wash away or otherwise collapse.  In the 1700s, this limit was only about 10m because they had not yet invented steel rebar to protect concrete and masonry against the shearing force of currents. Infact, even today using modern materials, the deepest bridge pier in the world is only 74m; so, this would probably be an unbuildable bridge, even by today's standards.
That said, there is no reason to assume that the bridge has to cross any particularly great depths.  For example, Adam's Bridge is a 48 km long sunken land bridge between Sri Lanka and India. It averages just 1 meter deep connecting the 65,600 square km island of Sri Lanka to the mainland. Another option would be an estuary lagoon. A barrier reef or barrier islands can trap the sediment from a river causing a very shallow and flat oceanic shelf to extend as much as 100km out to sea. Small islands inside of these lagoons are not uncommon, or your necromancer's island could be part of the barrier system itself.
As for keeping the grandiose feel of "crossing the ocean" by bridge this does not actually require great depths.  It is very rare for any part of the ocean to be clear enough to be able to see the bottom at depths of more than 1-2m anyway; so, a 3-10m deep lagoon is virtually indistinguishable from a 2000m deep oceanic trench. Just make it deep enough to drown in, and it won't really impact your narrative in any meaningful way.
A more shallow body of water also makes a larger and more impressive above the water presence possible.  The deeper your piers, the more stress they are already under making larger above the water features less plausible.
Issue #2: Your undead are mostly useless

They can be ordered to perform low level human tasks. Not dissimilar to construction workers.


They can not be expected to do complicated stuff like mix chemicals.

These are mutually exclusive because construction is mostly complicated stuff like mixing chemicals. Construction work, especially 18th century construction work, is not unskilled labor. Construction workers have to be precise and deliberate in nearly everything they do, and they need to have strong discernment skills to be able work with the irregular materials that would have been common before modern standardization and industry.

Masonry requires being able to lay stones very precisely to maintain a flat face because even small margins of error can compound in layer after layer until your face becomes bowed and unstable.  So, every single stone they lay must be a deliberate choice made with consideration of what is already under it and what goes on top of it. They also need to be able to identify bad stones.  If a quarry delivers a stone with a soft spot in it, it is the masson's job to identify and reject it. Brickwork takes less discernment of your materials, but you have to be very precise and consistent with your mortar to keep things straight. If a zombie can't measure or learn to be very accurate in his visual approximations, they can't do any masonry whatsoever.

For the wooden bits of the bridge, Carpentry requires measuring, cutting, and fitting wood at tolerances of about 1 millimeter.  Especially for mortise and tenon construction which was still the norm in the 1700s.  Lumber is also a very inconsistent material.  Carpenters need to be able to examine the bow, cut, grain, and knots of a board to determine if it will be suitable for a given application.  You could probably use the zombies to help with driving the piles but even with old school drop weight pile drivers, this only saves you about 12 man hours per pile which is not much compared to the other carpentry tasks like building the truss, retaining walls, etcs.

Concrete work is chemistry.  It requires actual mixing of chemicals and an awareness of what it should look and feel like to compensate for the irregularities common in pre-modern concrete.  There are also considerations like environment, cure times, surfacing, making sure there are no air pockets, etc.  Mishandling of concrete will cause it to crack when it cures which will lead to your bridge collapsing; so, this is not a good job for zombies at all.

Even digging a hole can require a certain amount of care since a hapless zombie digging in the wrong place could flood your whole operation and drown all your skilled human labor.


All in all, I think your zombies could be helpful assistants for your human workers to help fetch tools and carry materials around the worksite, but they probably won't be able to replace more than 10-30% of a human workforce unless they are capable of learning and complex discernment, or at least retain skills from when they were alive: like if a skilled carpenter can make a skilled carpenter zombie, but just can't learn new skills in undeath.
The closest you can get
However, if you want inspiration for a really long bridge that does not take any extraordinary engineering to build, you should look at the Lake Pontchartrain Causeway.  It is a 38.35 km long over water bridge, but the water depth is just 4-5m so it would have been doable just fine using 1700s materials, equipment, and techniques, because it is basically just 2,246 very simple bridges daisy chained back to back.  This segmented approach means that you minium construction time is theoretically just the few weeks it would take to make 1 span assuming you have about 1930 crews to work on it. However, your actual time needed will be much longer than that because planning, hiring, reanimation, procurement, and building up the fleet of barges and heavy equipment you would need will all take time and resources unto itself, and at some point the time it takes to put together that many work crews exceeds the time you could save having each crew do more than one segments. The Lake Pontchartrain Causeway took just over a year to build, so given you lower tech but near unlimited wealth and manpower,  I would expect the project to take a similar amount of time once you "break ground", but before that, expect to spend years in planning and procurement to make sure you have all the logistical requirements in place to even get started.
Stylistically, I'd go for something like the Ponte de Lima Bridge as an example of and older style of segmented bridge, but just expand it to Lake Pontchartrain Causeway proportions:


However, the checkpoints could easily take several years to build depending on how elaborate they are.  Unlike the simple bridge segments which can be built in parallel, each of these have to be built from the bottom up in much more detail making them more comparable in design to building a sea fort.  While some smaller sea forts could be built in less than a year, most took several years to build.

Sorry I was not clear about the ability of the undead. I'd should have explained clearly what I meant with their limitations. As to water depth. I just used a real world example of a location I think is similar to mine. I have no problem in making it more shallow.
But is it realistic? Basically it's like things, continent, ocean, and 33 km away is the closest point on the island. I want the conditions to be bad enough to make this impressive but have no problem toning it down to make it realistic. So. What min-max water depth makes the most sense?

@Seallussus if you can make it shallower it is absolutly possible to build your bridge, lang brindges crossing shallow water are called causeways and only have logistical/economical  limits not physical ones.

@Seallussus  Adam's Bridge is a 48 km long sunken land bridge between Sri Lanka and India.  It averages just 1 meter deep connecting the 65,600 square km island of Sri Lanka to the mainland.  Another option would be an estuary lagoon. A barrier reef or barrier islands can trap the sediment from a river causing a very shallow and flat oceanic shelf  to extend as much as 100km out to sea.  Small islands inside of these lagoons are not uncommon, or your necromancer's island could be part of the barrier system itself

There are coulple of issues to consider:
First, does the bridge NEED to be exactly 33 kilometers and straight? The bottom of the sea is very uneven, it would almost certainly be easier, faster, and possibly even cheaper to just build a 50-ish km bridge that weaves around the deepest chasms, and connects underwater shallows instead. Follow the geography.
Can the bridge float, wholly or in parts? This would make it far easier to make, and vastly cheaper as well as more practical (a floating bridge can be lifted by the defenders to deny the enemy access, or to let friendly ships sail through.)
Assuming you agree, the most practical way to make that bridge would be:

send undead to map the sea bottom between the endpoints

send undead to build bridge supports and towers on shallows and underwater hills. These are unlikely to be evenly spaced, which is not a problem but a feature

don't bother laying down stone. Just use the undead workforce to make gargantuan amounts of pumice-rich concrete, and pour it into underwarter moulds until the top emerges, then raise it with iron-rebar reinforced concrete (bronze rebar would be even better)

Once the Towers are done, have your undead horde chop down entire forests, and build giant rafts out of logs. Have the logs charred and tarred on the surface, so they won't rot. If possible, pick oak and larch wood for this. Cover the bottoms of rafts with bronze or copper plates, so that the barnacles would not eat into the wood.

steal or buy all the iron in the nearest kingdom and have it forged into a several dozen kilometer long chains. If possible, coat at least some of the chain links in bronze, or even make some out of bronze.

chain the rafts together into a 50 mile long floating bridge connected to the towers. Make sure each section of the floating bridge has at least some "slack" so that it would rise and fall with the waves and not resist them.

now, that the raft-bridge is done, it gives you access to reinforce some sections of the bridge with concrete pillars, until a concrete bridge replaces the wooden one in some places. But do not try to replace the whole bridge: the flimsy, wobbly nature of the raft bridge is your greatest defense. Your bridge guards can always cut off, or spool out sections of the raft bridge to foil any kind of assault. Or they can just slack down the chain on one side of the bridge and pull on the opposite side, to flip the attackers into the sea. Your whole bridge is now a giant drawbridge than can transform into a slide or a pallisade to foil any kind of attack.

suspended wood bridges also allow you to add extra features. You can suspend one bridge right over another, to double the traffic, and be able to rain down death on anyone on the lower bridge. You can run raft bridges in parallel, like a wooden highway. You can branch the bridge into a series of piers, breakwaters and loading jetties. Now your bridge is also the greatest seaport mankind ever seen, and it can reconfigure as needed.

defense: since you have plenty of undead, you can wall off your bridge with yet another layer of rafts, chained to the bottom. Any ship that would try to come close enough to baord the bridge, would need to physically push through a floating fortification swarming with zombies. Inversely, the floating fortification can open up to let friendly ships in, and become their protection, from the enemy and the waves.

defense: there will be parts of the bridge that you never want accessed by the enemy. Corral them with a length of concrete pillars that are just a meter or so underwater, so that the enemy ships would break upon them.

Caisson bunkers. Since your worforce is undead, have them construct caissons and tunnels underwater, then pump air into them. You now have underwater bunkers that cannot be ever breached with 1700s military technology, and can store your valuables, soldiers, horses (as long as the zombies are pumping air in),and can be used for sneaky surprise attacks. Hell, just order your undead to dig you a 33 km long tunnel through the sea floor connecting the two points. it will likely take centuries, but aren't you guys deathless anyway? In the meantime, you have your fancy bridge to use.
-misc: your bridge would have so much surface area, that you can easily attach several square km of fish farms, clam farms, passive nets, watermills, and water desalination tarps to it. The living soldiers on your bridge would be able to feed themselves (as long as they like seafood) and sell the excess fish/salt for cash, thus paying for your bridge.

oh, and about payments: your bridge would not only generate bridge tolls, but passive income from the port tax. It will almost certainly pay for itself many times over.

Bonus points: creating a 33 kilometers long trade hub would make you the absolute darling of the locals. You just uplifted the economy of the entire region, they will easily forgive you for being a Necromancer. Within a few decades, you will have local fishermen and merchants chanting praising songs in your name, and people are going to hug and kiss your undead minions for all the good work done. Your island and the bridge are now like New York, London, Amsterdam and Shanghai rolled in one, greatly enriching the world around it.



This is a wealth of information. I did not consider the secondary economic uses. At first it's just a classic: I have wealth and power and I will do something people can't dream of. But love the whole fishing and watermills and all that. Really fits my idea. I'm not sold on the floating aspect, it is envisioned to a be an edifice, it has to be permanent. I managed defenses with two castles controlling the start and finish of the bridge. I just gave the 33 km number because that's the shortest distance. But I get your point. Really great stuff overall.

@Seallussus Tbf, a floating city is pretty permanent, and possibly more resilient than a normal bridge since it's easier to maintain rafts than it Is to maintain pillars. Not to mention if it across an important strait, it will be rolling in cash to maintain itself, since trading with them is the only way to get goods to the other side.

Why even bother with the pillars then? Just have the entire bridge be made floating. Sure it'll move around a bit, but there's enough slack to avoid to much drift.

@Bubbles It is not possible to have the entire floating bridge made with 1700s technology, over a span of 33 km, without it snapping. The tension from the waves pressing on it would snap the chains like it was twine. Even with he gentles waves, we are talking about billions of tons of water pressing on its entire side. The bridge must be separated into short spans between pillars, so that the force on each span is reduced.

@GoingDurden Fair enough, I didn't think of that.

If your corpses can work at the bottom of the sea, then they can help lay piles using stones or tree-trunks lowered from the surface. They may not be able to see at great depths but a great deal could be done just by touch to guide blocks lowered from above.
Trajan's bridge spanned the Danube. It was built between 103 and 105 AD. It was about 1 km long with 20 spans of 50m. The piles were 45m high. These piles were built by building a coffer dam around the site at low water, so your necromancer would need other techniques for the depths, but all the other building techniques should work. The wooden arches were probably assembled on land and shipped out.
In 1502, Leonardo da Vinci had a proposal for a bridge over the Bosphorus. This would have been built of stone and had a span of 240m. If the deepest part is less than 240m wide, they could span that in a single arch. The supports at either edge would've to be massive, and resist horizontal forces, as Leonardo's design buttressed itself sideways. The piles on Trajan's bridge only needed to take the weight of the arches vertically.
The Lateran Obelisk was a single stone 32m tall that was quarried as a single unit in Ancient Egyptian times, and re-erected a bit shorter in medieval times. It is feasible to sink a stone pile to a depth of 30m at low tide using medieval technology, but beyond that we would have to invent something new. The Claudian Lighthouse at Ostia was built in 42 AD on foundations made by sinking a barge that had been used for transporting an obelisk. It is not unreasonable to imagine towing out deep sea pilings in sections, and then sinking one on top of another.
The Thunder Stone weighed 1450 tons, later shaped to 1240 tons was moved by land and sea for the base of an equestrian statue for Catherine the Great. This was done using technology that would have been recognised by the ancients. I can find no record of anyone sinking bridge piles to 100m but it is quite feasible for large stones to be shaped, moved to site, and then sunk to the sea-bed.

That same article also claims that the piles on Trajan's bridge only reach 19m high.  Since the danube is 8m at its deepest point, I think there is in issue with that article.  Based on how high the banks of the danube are and how deep the water is, I believe "45m high" is simply incorrect.  Probably a unit translation error.

A 33 Km Stone bridge would be quite the engineering feat.
Using 1700s technology, we could reasonably have a bridge span of 72m This is based off of this Stone Bridge, built in the late 1300s - which was not surpassed until later on
So you would need 450 or so Pillars - of which 10 would be turned into your Castles.
The problem here is you need some of them to be sunk up to 250 metres deep - which is far deeper than is practical, with 1700s technology.
This leads me to a Frame Challenge!
Now, if you go to the 1800s, you get access to the following:

Victorian Cement (1858 via Joseph Bazalgette)
Caisson Engineering (will get to this in a bit)
Suspension Bridge engineering (1815)

If you also reduce your water depth from 250 metres, to 100, you can use Caissons for your support towers.
Now, in Victorian times, when the effects of high pressure on the human body wasn't understood - there was a limit to how deep a Caisson could go - as workers would get the bends when they went from the high pressure Caisson to the normal atmosphere - however - your Zombie workers aren't going to be worried about getting the Bends.
With stone/concrete pillars, you could have a Suspension style bridge, with a much longer span (170 metres for the Menai bridge), less towers means quicker and easier to build (as this is where your time and effort would be taken up - getting the foundations correct)
Also using the Menai bridge as our benchmark - that took... 7 years to build! Although this bridge would be much more technically demanding - the fact that you have a near unlimited slave labour force mean I think we could do it.
So, to recap - with 1700s tech, I think this is a... Bridge too far (sorry, I had to) - but if you can sneak into the 1800s and make your waters a little bit shallower - I think that this is within the realm of possibility

Just use an infinite fleet of supply ships to dump hundreds of tons of granite blocks into the channel to build up the foundation one after another in parallel.

You're a necromancer. Fleshcraft.
The average body area for an adult is about 2 m^2, giving a lie-flat area of 0.66 m^2. A 33 km long, 24 meter wide bridge will require 792,000 m^2, or 2,736,000 corpses to cover it with a double layer of interlocking, nailed, bolted, and tied together decomposing bodies. Make it 6,000,000 for a 3-corpse-deep road surface, plus the occasional support pile with floaters on the bottom.
World population around 1700 was about 610,000,000, so you'd only need to zombify or dig up and reanimate 1% of the world's population to build the bridge.
Bonus: The bridge can assemble and disassemble to protect you from the enemies, and occasionally munch on any undesirables crossing it. You won't even need living guards, demanding gold, food, and other undeserved luxuries for their potentially traitorous selves.

Were your parents statistical necromancers, too? It seems to run in families.

The difficulty is in having infinite resources as this will skew the result. With infinite resources even with 1700's technology any number of vast fleets of vessels could be called upon to unload thousands of large granite blocks under the foundations of the structure on a continuous basis. The basic restraining issue is how fast can the ships unload?
Say 100 tonnes/minute: with each ship having several hundred tonnes aboard and being able to get clear for the next ship within a few minutes.
Average water depth ... say (50+250)/2 = 150m...
Space between piers on the bridge say 20m using 1700's technology.
To a good approximation all 33km of the channel would have to be filled in to reduce its depth to a few metres to enable piers every 20m
Assume that boats can operate with a 20m gap between them (1650 ships every few minutes but who's counting ships) and the whole bridge foundation can be built in parallel at an angle from the sea bed of 45 degrees (triangular cross section: 150x150x20/2 = 225,000 1m blocks at 3 tonnes each = 675,000 tonnes.
at 100tonnes/minute that's 6750 minutes or just under 5 days to build the whole  foundation across 33km as it will all be built in parallel as there are infinite resources.
After that all the bridges will need to be built on top of the ridge foundation (in parallel as there are infinite resource). How long to build a very large 17th century bridge? Probably the longest part as it's difficult to access but with as many workers as required, the undead and as much pre-prepared building material as needed available on the decks of ships all around probably a few weeks say 6 weeks.
Then the castles (also built in parallel) again difficult to access but say anther 6 weeks. Job done in 13 weeks maybe allow 4 months for overruns and "difficulties". :o)

I said practically. Then I edited the answer. What do I get? 4 troll votes.
And people acting like it's a gotcha moment.
Also ignore everything else about all the other limitations.
I mean can you build me a space ship that goes to Andromeda with infinite resources but our current tech and you have 7 years?
Probably not. You think it makes it a valid question. But guess not

In that case the problem is that we have to juggle with "practically" and "infinite resources". If it's truly infinite resources then it could happen fairly quickly as described. If it's a matter of practicality then the answer is it is not remotely practical and it's not going to happen with 1700's technology. So how are we supposed to find an answer between these extremes?

It does not work because you are ignoring everything else. Even when I edited the question removing that. u ignore it.
Even when the question has many other limitations u ignore it.
I simply can't force people to read basic English and I can't force them to be reasonable. Even now u are doing it. Can you find a cure for all cancers in 7 years with our tech and infinite resources? A ship that travels to Andromeda?...etc. ignore everything and proceed to judge based on one aspect. Ok. Clearly this is the mentality of people that want to help. I know people here have issues with help but wow
